# Untracker files after git pull

Tags: git

My intention was to create a local repository, and then to pull from an existing remote branch (which is a develop branch in my case), with:

```
git checkout -b <local_name> <remote_repo>/<remote_branch_name>
```

After that, I did `git status` and found different untracked files.

Since this local repository is new and I haven't made any local changes, how is this possible?

After that, is it so possible to push untracked files?

**EDIT:**

I've tried `git reset --hard`, and after `git status` I have the same untracked files.

Comment: An *untracked file* is a file that exists in your working tree, but not in Git's index. How that file got into your working tree is something of a mystery: had Git put it there during `git checkout`, Git would have put a copy of that same file into Git's index, and it would not be untracked. So something not-Git must have put that file there. *Anything* that can create files on your computer could have done that, though.

Comment: Running `git reset --hard` won't help because this only re-sets the files that Git is tracking. That is, for each file that's in Git's index, Git replaces *both* of the two copies of that file—the index one, and the one in your working tree—with the one from the current commit. Git does this even if something has removed the working-tree copy, so this will get removed files back as long as they're in the current commit. (I'm omitting several other rather confusing cases here to keep things simple.)

Comment: The most common culprits here are weird OS issues (macOS has some file name construction problems that don't normally occur on Linux for instance) or using a cloud-synced folder (Dropbox, iCloud, etc) to hold a repository and working tree. If you're doing the latter, don't do that.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. My issue was caused by `Symbolic links` (which appeared as untracked files). I had to manually delete them in the working tree. Then after a `git pull`, everything was ok.

Comment: Ah: Git on Windows is somewhat weird about symbolic links, as the support *for* symlinks on Windows is a bit iffy (some file systems have them and some do not and even on those that have them you can enable or disable them administratively). You need a Windows expert, which I am not, to know how to do that stuff there.

Comment: @torek for the record, I'm using Ubuntu.